# How to check if jQuery.ajax() request header Status is "304 Not Modified"?

Tags: ajax, jquery, header, http-status-code-304

How to check if [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request header Status is "304 Not Modified"?

`jqXHR.status` usually returns `200`, even when requested header is "304 Not Modified".

`ifModified:true` [does not help](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-fix-browser-cache-and-notmodified-respond-for-json-jquery-ajax-ifmodified-true-break-on-data-respond) a lot because it breaks XHR data request.

Comment: Short answer is no. However, this is a possible duplicate of [Determining what jQuery .ajax() resolves a string of redirects to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767618/determining-what-jquery-ajax-resolves-a-string-of-redirects-to) Though not the exact same question, the concept is the same--XHR spec does not require any notification of 3xx responses.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need to do the ETag checking manually, from your javascript, the browser will handle it for you. So unless you have a special reason for doing so, generally you don't need to check for 304 response

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Without handling cache headers manually, it is not possible. Normally, 304 responses are not made available through the [XHR API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20091119/):

> For 304 Not Modified responses that are a result of a user agent generated conditional request **the user agent must act as if the server gave a 200 OK response with the appropriate content**.

jQuery normally doesn't know there was a 304 response, because the browser tells polite lies to JavaScript about what is actually happening over the network.

But there is good news (kind of): you *can* get Ajax to produce a 304 response, but only by manually setting the [HTTP cache headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` in the request:

> The user agent must allow `setRequestHeader()` to override automatic cache validation by setting request headers (e.g., `If-None-Match`, `If-Modified-Since`), in which case 304 Not Modified responses must be passed through.

So, you can use code like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "foo.html");
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Fri, 15 Feb 2013 13:43:19 GMT");
xhr.send();
```

One fundamental difficulty is *how do you know what last-modified date or [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) to send?* The browser has cache information that it uses for sending requests, but it won't share that information with JavaScript. Fortunately, jQuery keeps track of the `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers from Ajax responses, so you can use `ifModified:true` to have jQuery set those header values the next time it sends a request for that resource.

Two things to note about this:

- 304 responses do not carry data. This is by design. The assumption is that if you have elected to use caching, you *should have a copy of the data already in your cache*! If getting no data from the sever is a problem (i.e., because you don't already have that data) why are you using caching? Caching should be used when you have the old data on hand and only want new data; thus, getting back no data with a 304 should not be a problem.
- jQuery must have a last-modified date or an ETag (to use with `If-None-Match`) stored from a previous request. The process goes like this:

  - First fetch: jQuery has no cache information, so it doesn't send `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`. When the response comes back, the server may announce a last-modified data or an ETag, which jQuery stores for future use.
  - Subsequent fetches: jQuery has cache information from the last fetch and forwards that data to the server. If the resource has not changed, the Ajax request gets a 304 response. If the resource has changed, the Ajax request gets a 200 response, along with new cache information for jQuery to use for its next fetch.
  - jQuery *does not* persist cache information (e.g., in cookies) between page reloads, however. Therefore, the first fetch of a resource after a page reload will *never* be a 304, because jQuery has no cache information to send (i.e., we reset back to the "first fetch" case). There is no reason why jQuery *couldn't* persist cache information, but at present it doesn't.

The bottom line here is that you can use cache headers to get a JavaScript 304 response, but you can't access the *browser's own* ETag or last-modified date for a particular resource. So, the browser itself might know caching information about a resource, but your JavaScript code does not. In that case, the browser will use its cache headers to potentially get a real 304 response, but forward a 200 response to your JavaScript code, because JavaScript didn't send any cache information.

It is not possible to make JavaScript 304 requests align perfectly with actual network 304 responses, because the cache information known by your browser and the cache information known by your JavaScript code may differ in unpredictable ways. However, getting 304 requests correctly most of the time is good enough for most practical development needs.

## Example

Here's a brief server example written in Node.js (but it should be simple enough to port to other langauges):

```
require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers["if-modified-since"]);

  // always send Last-Modifed header
  var lastModDate = "Fri, 13 Feb 2013 13:43:19 GMT";
  res.setHeader("Last-Modified", lastModDate);

  // if the request has a If-Modified-Since header,
  //   and it's newer than the last modification,
  //   then send a 304 response; otherwise send 200
  if(req.headers["if-modified-since"] &&
     Date.parse(lastModDate) <= Date.parse(req.headers["if-modified-since"])) {
    console.log("304 -- browser has it cached");
    res.writeHead(304, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end();
  } else {
    console.log("200 -- browser needs it fresh");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('some content');
  }

}).listen(8080);
```

When running this server, you can load the page in your browser and perform two different tests in your browser console:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/");
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() { console.log(xhr.status); }
```

This script will always see a `200` response, even if the browser supplies a `If-Modified-Since` request header and gets a `304` (which will happen all requests after the first, after the browser sees the server's `Last-Modifed` response header).

By contrast, this script will *always* see 304 response:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Fri, 15 Feb 2013 13:43:19 GMT");
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() { console.log(xhr.status); }
```

The script supplies its own `If-Modified-Since` request header (two days after the server's last-modified date); it does not rely on whatever the browser supplies for `If-Modified-Since`, and therefore is allowed (per the XHR spec) to see 304 responses.

Finally, this script will always see a `200`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Fri, 12 Feb 2013 13:43:19 GMT");
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() { console.log(xhr.status); }
```

This is because the script uses a `If-Modified-Since` that is prior to the server's last-modified date, so the server always sends a `200`. The server won't send a `304` because it assumes the client doesn't have a cached copy of the most recent version (i.e., the client announces that it's seen changes since Feb 12, but there was a change on Feb 13 that the client apparently hasn't seen).

Comment: I checked your `If-Modified-Since`+`Last-Modified` method with native XMLHttpRequest 2 and unfortunately Chrome always returns 200  and Firefox 301 cached result. Looks like there are no valid  XMLHttpRequest cache validation possible at all.

Comment: @Binyamin I have reproduced the behavior described in my answer and added a complete server and client example. Are you sure your server was correctly configured to send 304 responses in response to recent `If-Modified-Since` values? The script can only observe 304 responses when the server actually sends 304 responses. Using an explicit `If-Modified-Since` allows existing 304 response to be visible to the script (rather than hidden as 200); it does not generate a 304 status where one doesn't already exist in the actual response.

Comment: @apsillers, I just sent you an email with full code related to issue. Hope you will have ideas to hack the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Use Date instead of Last-Modified. If Date is less than time when request performed then the response was returned from cache

Answer (score 0):

Also the headers will be cached if the response comes from cache. I took this as a chance. 
My server sends a unique md5 header. This has not the same effect like ?query=time(). Now on JS side verify the lastest md5 header with the current. If you receive the same MD5 header as before the response is coming from cache. I forgot all about JQuery but saw it's possible to set and read headers.

```
<?php
$oldMD5=filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'HTTP_CONTENT_MD5',int);
if(!empty($oldMD5)){
  header('Content-MD5: '.(1+(int)$oldMD5));
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
<script>
var oldMD5=0;
//your Ajax implementation 
Ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-MD5',''+oldMD5);
var newMD5=parseInt(Ajax.getResponseHeader('Content-MD5'),10);
if(newMD5 && oldMD5<newMD5,10){
  oldMD5=newMD5;
  //not cached
}else{
  //cached
}
```

This is a little bit abuse, because md5 should be a hash for to verify that the 'decoded data are the same data that were initially sent'.

Answer (score -3):

I have kind of implementation in 
https://github.com/laukstein/ajax-seo/blob/cbed03222d89f6f7e75dc49ce8882c30201bbb86/index.php#L266-274

```
var cache;

$.ajax({
    ...
    beforeSend: function() {
        cache = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('The content not cached jet.');
        }, 300);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (cache) {
            clearTimeout(cache);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -5):

Maybe try this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your-url',
    dataType: 'script',
    complete: function(xhr) { 
        if (xhr.status == 304) return;
        // or better: if (xhr.status != 200) return;
        // your code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: XHR `readsystatechange` is not fired by 3xx responses, so `complete` will not be entered while `status` is 304.

Answer (score -5):

open your browsers inspector and it will show you info on the ajax request, including the status.

for chrome, right click and choose inspect element, then go to the Network tab.

for firefox, just use firebug and follow the same steps.

Comment: This only helps the OP know as an observing human. I believe he would like his program to "know" and make decisions with that info.