# How can Javascript view the ETAG value of a HTTP response? Can ETAG be included in a request?

Tags: javascript, etag

Is it possible for javascript to read the ETAG value of a HTTP response?

Are there any issues in writing out an ETAG value in a HTTP Request to the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross Domain Resource Sharing GET: 'refused to get unsafe header "etag"' from Response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822985/cross-domain-resource-sharing-get-refused-to-get-unsafe-header-etag-from-re)

Comment: Through AJAX? Or just regularly loaded?

Comment: @Waynn - Both if possible.. I'm reading Jmort's link, though it's not totally clear to me

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12501696) for an answer to the second question (well, both really, could be a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a regularly loaded page, I think the HTTP request/response is already complete so Javascript can't access that information.

If it's an AJAX call, jQuery has the jqXHR object (documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)), which says this.

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object. For example, it contains responseText and responseXML properties, as well as a getResponseHeader() method. When the transport mechanism is something other than XMLHttpRequest (for example, a script tag for a JSONP request) the jqXHR object simulates native XHR functionality where possible.

So you can call `getResponseHeader()` on the returned object in your success call to parse them out.