# chrome browser not sending 'If-None-Match' for xhr

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, etag

I'm using an angular service to GET a resource via a rest api. The server sets the `ETag` header to some value and it also sets `Cache-Control: no-cache` in it's response.

This works as expected using Firefox, but when I access the same app using Chrome, it is not sending the `If-None-Match`. I've tried on current Chrome dev and stable channels on both a Mac and an Ubuntu box, and it was the same on both, while Firefox was adding the `If-None-Match` correctly.

Now, there are other non-xhr/static resources that are fetched conditionally and all those requests correctly get a `304 NOT MODIFIED` response.

Is there anything I can do to get more information about why Chrome is not sending the `If-None-Match` header only for XHR requests?

Answer (score 6):

If you're issuing an Ajax query in Chrome over HTTPS, any certificate errors, such as using a self-signed cert on your API server, prevent the response from being cached. This seems to be by design.

Evidently a [Chrome defect](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41880) [existed](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/byhp0EODjzc) but was [fixed](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/63100) in Webkit and made it into Chromium / Chrome around 2010.

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173656/how-to-check-if-jquery-ajax-request-header-status-is-304-not-modified) recommends setting the If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match headers manually using jQuery's ifModified: true and cache: true options. Unfortunately this won't over-ride Chrome's intended behavior to not cache HTTPS responses from a server with a self signed certificate.

Testing on a server with a valid signed SSL certificate solved the issue for me; Chrome received 304's for text/html content as expected, using the default jQuery AJAX methods.