# angular $http and status code 304

Tags: angularjs, http, http-status-code-304

When the server sends 304, the browser handles it automatically and the $http receives status 200. I want to handle it myself so i don't reload my view when 
content has not changed.

I want to do something like this:

```
$http.get("api/endpoint").then(function(response){
    if(response.status != 304)
        //update view with response.data
    }
    else{
        // do nothing
    }
 });
```

Comment: seriously man. Plz share your code to give every1 a better perspective.

Comment: I think you can check it at $httpProvider

Comment: I looked at $httpProvider documentation but i don't find a way to forward the 304 status code. I also try with $http Interceptor but the 304 does not reach there either.

Comment: So, do you face any error while doing this?

Comment: No there is no error ,only that the view is reloading with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a more general issue.
Here is another post about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173656/how-to-check-if-jquery-ajax-request-header-status-is-304-not-modified)